# Normal php in a Cake PHP app and using htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a normal php script which I want to use in a CakePHP application (created by a previous developer). I have made a folder  in my CakePHP webroot folder:

Httpdocs -> app -> webroot -> folderx

Is it possible to run a standalone script in this folder?

Also, my script takes in an id, for example www.domain.com/folderx/index.php?id=123 and draws the information (ex name of the product) from the DB. However, I wish to rewrite the URL to:
www.domain.com/folderx/name-of-the-product. Is this possible at all?
The webroot already has an .htaccess file which handles the CakePHP rewrites. Would I be able to use a new .htaccess file with the rewrite instructions in www.domain.com/folderx/ for my standalone script.

Comment: My htacess file contains the following: `code`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


</IfModule>`code`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not doing it within the CakePHP system?
You could make it a controller(folderx), and add an action there (ex: product) which would then take the name of the product as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the existing rewrite rules to *not* rewrite requests that include /folderx/ to CakePHP. If you need help with that and the mod_rewrite manual isn't enough, share your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your htaccess, in webroot, must contain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

In this case, all the folders and files in the webroot should open normally